# Progressive disclosure techniques to allow advanced simplicity for web apps?

Tags: website-design

What progressive disclosure techniques where the information and options given starts out small and lets the user decide what they want expanded on can I use in a web app?

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following:

- In various situations, for example forms, you can use links:
  The link can say something like "would you like to add this capability?" and once pressed, reveal a hidden section.
- There's the classic "advanced" approach, which can be implemented as a button or a tab, often more in use in applications.
- Consider what this site is doing - when you vote up an answer to your own question, the application reminds you that you can accept it as well.
- A variation, to be used very carefully:
  If it's an application where actions are more spread out, I would consider having some balloons pop (rarely and unobtrusively) indicating something can be performed / is available.
- Another thing would be to suggest something to the user after he has become more "advanced", i.e. automatically reveal a feature after the user has used a related basic feature several times.

**Edited:**

I also like the approach of waiting for the user to express interest in an object, usually detectable by hovering over it with the mouse pointer, and then (after a slight delay perhaps) automatically reveal more options on that object.

Comment: I like how you mention that the ballon/popup should be used unobtrusively. I really like how the bar pops up on the Stack Exchange sites across the top (can't remember its proper name) To me it just seems unobtrusive. Where as sometimes I go to other sites and immediately get assaulted with a "please login/sign up" popup.

Comment: **@James Khoury:** I think _Notification bar_ is a decent name for that, although I find that _the bar that pops up on the Stack Excange sites across the top_ is a very good description :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of excellent articles on responsive disclosure:

[Pattern Responsive Disclosure](http://quince.infragistics.com/html/PatternView.aspx?id=b371616f-c92c-4fe2-8b54-f75cc1799b58)

[Designing Interfaces Article on Responsive Disclosure](http://www.designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=Responsive_Disclosure)

You could also consider looking into the responsive enabling pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For information only (not options)

You can make something like Google Wonder wheel where you start out with a small amount of info and as you click you get more options.

This is not for everything and is limited to browsing large data sets.

[Google Wonder wheel](http://www.google.com/search?q=user+interface+blog&hl=en&tbo=1&rlz=1R2ADBF_enIL380&prmd=ilvbn&source=lnt&tbs=ww:1&sa=X&ei=diRpTLP4FdCw4QblnYiZBA&ved=0CBsQpwU#q=user+interface+wiki&hl=en&sa=X&tbo=1&rlz=1R2ADBF_enIL380&tbs=ww:1&prmd=ilvbn&fp=8da47ac806d1c372)

Another option for large data sets is the new [silverlight pivotviewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/default.aspx)
(click launch pivotviewer)

These are both good for veiwing large data sets and have nothing to do with functionality